# Redrawing a canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a board where user has to select certain things.I need to redraw the board several times during the execution

```
//function to clear board
function clearBoard(){
   for(var i=0;i<32;i++){
     var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"+(i+1));
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
     // remove all classes from canvas
     $("#c").removeClass();
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
   } 
 }
```

when this function gets executed, board gets cleared. But when I redraw the canvases, previous drawings appear again and they overlap with new one

function to draw board

```
function drawBoard(level){
   type = shuffleArray(); // it gives a shuffled array between 1 to 32
   //console.log(type);
   for(var i=0;i<32;i++){
     var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"+(i+1));
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

     if(type[i]%3==0){  // draw a rectangle
         count++; //  increase the count of rectangle
         c.className="rectangle";
         ctx.rect(20, 20, 75, 50);
     }
     else if(type[i]%3==1){ // draw a circle
         c.className="circle";
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(50,37,25,0,2*Math.PI);
     }
     else{    // draw a square
          c.className="square";
          ctx.rect(20, 20, 50, 50);
     }

     ctx.stroke();
   }

   alert("level "+(5-level)+" click all rectangles"); 

   var timer = 15*level * 1000;

   setInterval(function(){ alert("time up,try again");   drawBoard(level); }, timer);
```

}

Comment: You do not seem to be calling `clearBoard` in your snippet. Are you sure it's called once before `drawBoard`?

Comment: Yes sir, I am calling it.I even tried moving clearBoard() inside drawBoard () but still its not working.

Comment: Have you tried `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` or `c.width = c.width;`?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the code.

Comment: `$("#c").removeClass();` is certainly a problem, though possibly not THE problem. Instead, do `$(c).removeClass()` or `c.className = ''`.